# Create matrix and fill it in wolfram

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

i want to translate my C++ code to wolfram, to improve my calcs.
C++ code

```
for(int i = 0; i < N - 1; ++i){
        matrix[i][i] += L / 3 * uCoef  - duCoef / 2 - (double)du2Coef/L;
        matrix[i][i+1] += L / 6 * uCoef + duCoef / 2 + (double)du2Coef/L;
        matrix[i+1][i] += L / 6 * uCoef - duCoef / 2 + (double)du2Coef/L;
        matrix[i+1][i+1] += L / 3 * uCoef + duCoef / 2- (double)du2Coef/L;
    }
```

all this coef are const, N - size of my matrix.

Answer (score 1):

```
In[1]:= n = 4; uCoef = 2; duCoef = 3; du2Coef = 7; L = 11.;
matrix = Table[0, {n}, {n}];
For[i = 1, i < n, ++i,
  matrix[[i, i]] += L/3*uCoef - duCoef/2 - du2Coef/L;
  matrix[[i, i+1]] += L/6*uCoef - duCoef/2 - du2Coef/L;
  matrix[[i+1, i]] += L/6*uCoef + duCoef/2 + du2Coef/L;
  matrix[[i+1, i+1]] += L/3*uCoef - duCoef/2 + du2Coef/L];
matrix

Out[4]= {
  {5.19697, 1.5303, 0, 0},
  {5.80303, 11.6667, 1.5303, 0},
  {0, 5.80303, 11.6667, 1.5303},
  {0, 0, 5.80303, 6.4697}}
```

Each character that has been changed from your original is hinting there is a fundamental difference between C++ and Mathematica

Answer (score 0):

You should use `SparseArray` for such banded arrays in mathematica:

```
 n = 5; uCoef = 2; duCoef = 3; du2Coef = 7; L = 11.;
 matrix = SparseArray[
          {{1, 1} -> L/3*uCoef - duCoef/2 - du2Coef/L,
          {i_ /; 1 < i < n, i_} -> -duCoef + 2 L uCoef/3 ,
          {n, n} -> ( L/3 uCoef - duCoef/2 + du2Coef/L ),
          Band[{1, 2}] -> L/6 uCoef - duCoef/2 - du2Coef/L,
          Band[{2, 1}] -> L/6 uCoef + duCoef/2 + du2Coef/L}, {n, n}];

 MatrixForm@matrix
```

[image]

Even if you insist on the `For` loop, initialize the matrix as :

```
  matrix = SparseArray[{{_, _} -> 0}, {n, n}];
```